# Why sometimes extern crate is needed?

Tags: rust, module

I would like to know, why sometimes we need to use `extern crate` over `use`? I'm using the crate `wee_alloc` and to import its modules I have to use `extern crate`:

```
extern crate wee_alloc;

// Use `wee_alloc` as the global allocator.
#[global_allocator]
static ALLOC: wee_alloc::WeeAlloc = wee_alloc::WeeAlloc::INIT;
```

But with `web_sys` I can just use `use`.

Comment: You don't need the `extern crate` - only if you are using edition 2015.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of rust and I see `no wee_alloc external crate` error when using `use` instead of `extern crate`.

Comment: Can you provide the entire error message?

Comment: In 2021 there is no need to use it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**tldr**: You do not need to write extern crate anymore for external dependencies in Rust 2018. The code you provided without `extern crate` works just fine with `edition = "2018"` set in your `Cargo.toml`

### No more `extern crate`

You no longer need to write `extern crate` to import a crate into your project. Before:

```rust
// Rust 2015

extern crate futures;

mod foo {
    use futures::Future;
}
```

After:

```rust
// Rust 2018

mod foo {
    use futures::Future;
}
```

#### Macros

One other use for extern crate was to import macros; that's no longer needed. In Rust 2015, you would have written:

```rust
// Rust 2015

#[macro_use]
extern crate log;

fn main() {
    error!("oops");
}
```

Now, you write:

```rust
// Rust 2018

use log::error;

fn main() {
    error!("oops");
}
```

#### Renaming crates

If you've been using `as` to rename your crate like this:

```
extern crate futures as fut;
```

Then in Rust 2018, you simply do this:

```
use futures as fut;

use fut::Future;
```

### Sysroot Crates

There's one exception to this rule, and that's the "sysroot" crates. These are the crates distributed with Rust itself. For now, you still need to use `extern crate` for these crates:

- `proc_macro`
- `core`
- `std`

However, `extern crate std` and `extern crate core` are already implicit, so it is very rare that you will need to declare them manually.

Finally, on nightly, you'll need it for crates like:

- `alloc`
- `test`

Those are the only exceptions to the rule. Therefore, the code you provided without `extern crate` works just fine in Rust 2018:

```rust
#[global_allocator]
static ALLOC: wee_alloc::WeeAlloc = wee_alloc::WeeAlloc::INIT;
```

### Setting your Rust Edition

Just because you have the latest Rust *version* installed does not mean that you are compiling with the latest *edition*. To tell Cargo to use a specific edition, set the `edition` key/value pair. For example:

```rust
[package]
name = "foo"
edition = "2018"
```

If there's no `edition` key, Cargo will default to Rust 2015. But in this case, we've chosen 2018, and so our code is compiling with Rust 2018! *Thanks to @KevinReid for pointing this out*

*This answer was derived from [The Rust Edition Guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html)*

Comment: That partially answers my question. I still need to use `extern crate wee_alloc`, otherwise the error pops up when compiling: `no wee_alloc external crate`

Comment: The code at the end of my answer does not work for you? What edition of Rust are you using?

Comment: This answer doesn't mention that you need to *specify* the edition in your `Cargo.toml` — otherwise it defaults to `'2015'` for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I think the distinction that's missing is that having _installed_ an up-to-date _version_ Rust does not mean that the chosen _language edition_ will be the latest.

Comment: Not a Rust expert, but I am in a `no_std` environment and using the `alloc` crate, which requires `extern crate alloc` with Rust 2018 edition.